# How to sort the dates from different objects with multiples dates inside of an array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array of objects that I gather from an API:

```
  const schedules = [
    {
        "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b4",
        "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",
        "scheduledDates": [
            {
                "date": "2023-04-17T18:00:00.000Z",
                "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",
                "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b5",
        "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",
        "scheduledDates": [
            {
                "date": "2023-04-19T10:30:00.000Z",
                "user": "64217a8dcc69c5fa48a5b484"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",
                "user": "6414be936b0bbf2bd8fa964f"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

How can I sort this array by the date inside schedulesDates array, keep the same array of objects structure, looking like this array:

```
const newSchedules = [
  {
      "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b4",
      "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",
      "scheduledDates": [
          {
              "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",
              "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b5",
    "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",
    "scheduledDates": [
        {
            "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",
            "user": "6414be936b0bbf2bd8fa964f"
        }
    ]
},
  {
      "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b4",
      "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",
      "scheduledDates": [
          {
              "date": "2023-04-17T18:00:00.000Z",
              "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b5",
      "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",
      "scheduledDates": [
          {
              "date": "2023-04-19T10:30:00.000Z",
              "user": "64217a8dcc69c5fa48a5b484"
          }
      ]
  },
]
```

I have this function to handle the sort:

```
  const handleSort = () => {
    if (sortOrder === "asc") {
      setSortOrder("desc");
      return schedules.map((schedule) =>
      schedule.scheduledDates.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
      );
    } else {
      setSortOrder("asc");
      return schedules.map((schedule) =>
      schedule.scheduledDates.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))
    }
  };
```

But it sorts only within each array of scheduledDates. Thanks for helping.

Comment: btw if you are unwinding why have an array of 0 elements in the final result for scheduled dates. cant you have it like `{scheduledDates: {date,user}}`

Comment: You are saying __keep the same array of objects structure__ but then your expected format has 4 items instead of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `flatMap` and `map` to unwind the array. used `map` since I assumed that each `scheduledDates` can have a dynamic amount of data not just 2. If it is fixed to 2 don't use map just get the [0]th,[1]th and return.
Next is the usual sorting. I don't understand why the final result should have an array of just 1 element for `scheduledDates`. A better approach would be to have an object with  `date`,`user` properties. Anyway changing to that wont be difficult

```js
const schedules = [   {        "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b4",        "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",        "scheduledDates": [            {                "date": "2023-04-17T18:00:00.000Z",                "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"            },            {                "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",                "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"            }        ]    },    {        "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b5",        "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",        "scheduledDates": [           {                "date": "2023-04-19T10:30:00.000Z",                "user": "64217a8dcc69c5fa48a5b484"            },            {                "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",                "user": "6414be936b0bbf2bd8fa964f"            }        ]    },]

const res = schedules
  .flatMap(e => e.scheduledDates.map(d => ({...e,scheduledDates:[d]})))
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.scheduledDates[0].date) - new Date(b.scheduledDates[0].date))

console.log(res)
```

`scheduledDates` as an object

```js
const schedules = [   {        "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b4",        "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",        "scheduledDates": [            {                "date": "2023-04-17T18:00:00.000Z",                "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"            },            {                "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",                "user": "643701f7e5f61e6760f4d1f3"            }        ]    },    {        "_id": "6436b48b875967d0bea245b5",        "service": "64246dc9a2d61593d103c749",        "scheduledDates": [           {                "date": "2023-04-19T10:30:00.000Z",                "user": "64217a8dcc69c5fa48a5b484"            },            {                "date": "2023-04-12T18:00:00.000Z",                "user": "6414be936b0bbf2bd8fa964f"            }        ]    },]

const res = schedules
  .flatMap(e => e.scheduledDates.map(d => ({...e,scheduledDates:d})))
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.scheduledDates.date) - new Date(b.scheduledDates.date))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort this array of objects based on the dates in `scheduledDates`, you have to modify your sorting function. You can use the `sort()` method on the schedules array and pass a comparison function that compares the dates in the `scheduledDates` arrays.

It should work this way:

```
const handleSort = () => {
  if (sortOrder === "asc") {
    setSortOrder("desc");
    schedules.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(a.scheduledDates[0].date) - new Date(b.scheduledDates[0].date);
    });
  } else {
    setSortOrder("asc");
    schedules.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.scheduledDates[0].date) - new Date(a.scheduledDates[0].date);
    });
  }
};
```